# Only User Model is saving with empty Values to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

In Laravel 5.4 when I try to save User model to the database the values are not saved. I've set the fillable property as well.

It was working in Laravel 5.3. This issue is coming after upgrading the application into Laravel 5.4.

Below is a User model.

```
class User extends BaseModel implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, JWTSubject
{
    use SoftDeletes,
        UserAccess,
        UserAttribute,
        UserRelationship,
        Authenticatable,
        CanResetPassword,
        Notifiable;

    /**
     * Database Table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = "users";

    /**
     * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * Fillable Form Fields
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'status',
        'confirmed',
        'api_user',
        'confirmation_code',
        'account_id',
        'role_id',
        'cw_contact_id',
        'all',
        'all_locations',
        'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * Select HTML Preference
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $selectHTMLFormat = "[email]";

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'last_login'];
}
```

Please note the issue is with User Model only.

I'm saving User as below.

```
// Create User
        $user = $this->model->create([
            'first_name'        => $input['first_name'],
            'last_name'         => $input['last_name'],
            'username'          => $input['username'],
            'email'             => $input['email'],
            'password'          => bcrypt($input['password']),
            'confirmation_code' => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)),
            'confirmed'         => 1,
            'api_user'          => (isset($input['api_user']) ? $input['api_user'] : 0),
            'account_id'        => $input['account_id'],
            'role_id'           => (isset($input['role_id']) ? $input['role_id'] : 0),
            'all'               => (!isset($input['associated-permissions']) || $input['associated-permissions'] == 'all') ? 1 : 0,
            'status'            => (!isset($input['status']) || $input['status'] ? 1 : 0),
            'all_locations'     => $input['all_locations']
        ]);
```

Then the create method of BaseModel will be called and below is the code of it.

```
public static function create(array $attributes = Array())
{
    $user = access()->user();

    if($user)
    {
        $attributes['account_id'] = (!isset($attributes['account_id']) ? $user->account->id : $attributes['account_id'] );
    }

    $childClass     = get_called_class();
    $model          = new $childClass;
    $model->runActionLogger(false, 'create');

    return parent::query()->create($attributes);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: show us the code how you save

Comment: Everything looks OK in User model (without traits). You can use try-catch block to catch stack trace error and please share with us the results.

Comment: @SteD mentioned it in my question. How i save user.

Comment: @VolkanMetin ok let me check. and get back to you if there is any error.

Comment: why you create user with $this->model->create ? and where you call this?
Why you not use User::create ?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Because I want to log each create action. so I create one function in BaseModel and it will be called from the Repository.

Comment: what is `$this` when you call `$user = $this->model->create`?

Comment: **create** is a static method but U call it like a non static method....and please specify namespace of create user code(`$user = $this->model->create......`)

Comment: try Using $this::create() instead if $this->model->create().

Comment: If I'm not implementing CanResetPasswordContract then I'm able to create User like this way parent::query()->create($attributes); or with User Model Factory too. I'm not ale to understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I'm able to resolve issue by using Fill() method.

```
public static function create(array $attributes = Array())
{
    $user = access()->user();

    if($user)
    {
        $attributes['account_id'] = (!isset($attributes['account_id']) ? $user->account->id : $attributes['account_id'] );
    }

    $childClass     = get_called_class();
    $model          = new $childClass;

    $model->fill($attributes);
    $model->save();

    $model->runActionLogger($model, 'create');

    return $model;
}
```

Also By mistake I've added Construction on CanResetPassword Trait which causing issue as well. So If i remove that everything will work as before as well.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is most probably the new middleware in Laravel 5.4 called "Request Sanitization Middleware" as explained in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases.

Disable `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,` in app/Http/kernel.php and see what you get.

You can also check in /config/database.php and your mysql connection settings: `'strict' => true`, if so, set to `false`.

A good practice is using the model for user input. In this case, instead of `$user = $this->model->create(...)` populate you model with 
`$user = new \App\User($input)` and update your values from there, f.ex. 
`$user->confirmation_code = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));` and 
`$user->password = bcrypt($user->password);`

If fields are nullable, indicate as such in your migration file, f.ex. `$table->string('all')->nullable();`

If done just run `$user->save();`

Comment: This is not the case. Middleware is not the case. This above code is working for all other models. Just getting issue with user model.

Answer (score 5):

From 5.4 the `create()` function is not more defined in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

Is handled as *dinamic method call*, that is by calling one of these functions (dependig on if it's called statically or not):

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
// or
public function __call($method, $parameters)
```

In the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class.

Now I dont have all your code but, IMHO, I will try to change this line in your BaseModel class:

```
return parent::query()->create($attributes);
```

to this:

```
return $model->create($attributes);
```

or, even better for me, to this:

```
return (new static)->newQuery()->create($attributes);
```

Comment: When I'll use $model->create() it will call that model baseModel function only but not the Laravel illuminate. The other alternative is not working for user Model.

Comment: try the last one please

Comment: Tried but not getting success. I guess it is case of CanResetPasswordContract. If I'm not implementing it the above code will work.

Answer (score 2):

> In the
>   [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)
>   it says:
>
> ```
> $post = App\Post::find(1);
>
> $comment = $post->comments()->create([
>     'message' => 'A new comment.',
> ]);
> ```

So

```
$user = $this->users()->create([
            'first_name'        => $input['first_name'],
            'last_name'         => $input['last_name'],
            'username'          => $input['username'],
            'email'             => $input['email'],
            'password'          => bcrypt($input['password']),
            'confirmation_code' => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)),
            'confirmed'         => 1,
            'api_user'          => (isset($input['api_user']) ? $input['api_user'] : 0),
            'account_id'        => $input['account_id'],
            'role_id'           => (isset($input['role_id']) ? $input['role_id'] : 0),
            'all'               => (!isset($input['associated-permissions']) || $input['associated-permissions'] == 'all') ? 1 : 0,
            'status'            => (!isset($input['status']) || $input['status'] ? 1 : 0),
            'all_locations'     => $input['all_locations']
        ]);
```

where `users()` is your public function but I don't know what is `$this` in your case but should be the model as in the example from documentation.

Why you're not using resource controllers? Or if you need to populate the db use a seeder
I think It will be more easy to manage.

Comment: I don't want to do like this. As I'm logging each activity so I need to bypass it baseModel only. And it is working with other models but the issue is with User model only.

Comment: @ViralSolani can you post more code, just to understand what is `$this`?

Answer (score 1):

So 2 things i can think off

1st there is no need to use

protected $guarded = [];

and

protected $fillable = [];

Guarded will assume everything is fillable if its not in here and fillable will assume everything is guarded unless in here.

To quote the docs

> While $fillable serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be mass assignable, you may also choose to use $guarded. The  $guarded property should contain an array of attributes that you do not want to be mass assignable. All other attributes not in the array will be mass assignable. So, $guarded functions like a "black list". Of course, you should use either $fillable or  $guarded - not both.

2nd to rule out any of the $this->model stuff try instantiate the class first and save them

```
use App\Path\To\Model as user;

$user = new user();
$user->first_name    = $input['first_name'];
$user->last_name     = $input['last_name'];
$user->username      = $input['username'];
$user->email         = $input['email'];
$user->password      = bcrypt($input['password']);
$user->confirmation_code = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(); true));
$user->confirmed     = 1;
$user->api_user      = (isset($input['api_user']) ? $input['api_user'] : 0);
$user->account_id    = $input['account_id'];
$user->role_id       = (isset($input['role_id']) ? $input['role_id'] : 0);
$user->all           = (!isset($input['associated-permissions']) || $input['associated-permissions'] == 'all') ? 1 : 0;
$user->status        = (!isset($input['status']) || $input['status'] ? 1 : 0);
$user->all_locations = $input['all_locations'];
$user->save();
```

Comment: I don't want to do like this. As I'm logging each activity so I need to bypass it baseModel only. And it is working with other models but the issue is with User model only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't use __construct method in Traits.

Please Refer PHP.net for more details about trait, they said "Using AS on a __construct method (and maybe other magic methods) is really, really bad."

You can use trait like following way.

```
class User extends BaseModel
{
    use userRelation
}

Trait userRelation
{
       public function getUserName()
       {
             return "Jhon Doe";
       }
}
```

I have created "userRelation" Trait which contains few useful code to re-use.

Please refer following link for more details - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Please try it and let me know if it won't work.
Thanks